# How to draw shapes in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to code paint-like programme. You can draw filled shapes by selecting which shape you want, click picturebox and drag mouse to get which size you want. But [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5BKm.png) can happens when I drag. When I use `refresh();`, shapes -which previously drawn- deletes itself. What should I do to draw filled shapes?

```
private void CizimPicture_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            cizim = true;
        }
        X1 = e.X;
        Y1 = e.Y;
    }

    private void CizimPicture_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        cizim = false;
    }

    private void CizimPicture_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!cizim) return;

        if (cizim == true)
        {
            X = e.X;
            Y = e.Y;
            X2 = (e.X - X1);
            Y2 = (Y1 - e.Y);

            if (dikdörtgen == true)
            {
                resmim.FillRectangle(renk.Brush, X1, Y1, X2, -Y2);
            }
            if (elips == true)
            {
                resmim.FillEllipse(renk.Brush, X1, Y1, X2, -Y2);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The program is doing exactly what it is supposed to do; when you redraw the screen you have to tell it *what to redraw* if there is something specific you want redrawn.  If you don't tell it to redraw anything then the result is that nothing is redrawn. If you want something redrawn when you redraw the screen, *write code that does that*.

Comment: I think you'll need to remember all of the shapes that have been drawn so far, so that you can redraw them when refresh is called, and the position of any shape that's in progress of being drawn. At a pinch you could draw your shapes onto a Bitmap and just display that, but that wouldn't work well for your drawing-in-progress shapes.

Comment: Rup is correct. Typically what you would do is remember the *previous* state of the screen in a bitmap, draw *that*, and then draw the *new shape* over top of the bitmap. Alternatively, you could remember *every shape that had been drawn*, and then *redraw them in the right order* when you redraw the screen.

Comment: I don't know how to draw my shapes into bitmap and display it again. And I tried to draw my shapes in Paint handler instead of MouseMove but it didn't work because I can't get coordinates. Actually I'm pretty new to programming. If I'm saying something irrational, sorry.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases whare you need to use CreateGraphics. You should use a combination of regular drawing in the Paint event using the e.Graphics object and a list of shape data. Plus current drawing on the MouseMove, testing for Button and using a Graphics created from the drawing surface control. You will need to call Refresh before and can then draw the new shape in its new size. The first drawing method will create persistant shapes, the 2nd non-persistent.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414334/how-to-draw-an-updating-line/38419518?s=22|19.0075#38419518) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019439/c-sharp-how-to-draw-a-rubber-band-selection-rectangle-on-panel-like-one-used-in/39179990#39179990) for  examples of drawing updating/rubberband shapes as well as ldrawing from lists of shape data..

Comment: I would highly recommend learning WPF instead of WinForms. And depending on what you're hoping to actually achieve with this, OpenTK is a fantastic OpenGL wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked for sample code that was both simple and worked and did not find anything. You do not need offscreen bitmaps or `CreateGraphics` for this, but you will need to handle tracking the mouse position, drawing to the screen, and adding drawn shapes to a list of shapes as Eric suggests. To handle interactive drawing you need to store the mouse state, initial click position, and current rectangle in your form handler:

```
bool mouseDown;
Point clickPos;
Rectangle rect;
```

Then when the user clicks, remember the initial position:

```
private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
    clickPos = e.Location;
    rect = new Rectangle(clickPos, new Size(0, 0));
}
```

While the user drags with the mouse down, create a rectangle encompassing the start and current location:

```
private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown)
    {
        this.Invalidate(rect);
        if (e.Location.X > clickPos.X && e.Location.Y > clickPos.Y)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(clickPos.X, clickPos.Y, e.Location.X - clickPos.X, e.Location.Y - clickPos.Y);
        }
        else if (e.Location.X > clickPos.X && e.Location.Y < clickPos.Y)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(clickPos.X, e.Location.Y, e.Location.X - clickPos.X, clickPos.Y - e.Location.Y);
        }
        else if (e.Location.X < clickPos.X && e.Location.Y < clickPos.Y)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y, clickPos.X - e.Location.X, clickPos.Y - e.Location.Y);
        }
        else if (e.Location.X < clickPos.X && e.Location.Y > clickPos.Y)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(e.Location.X, clickPos.Y, clickPos.X - e.Location.X, e.Location.Y - clickPos.Y);
        }

        this.Invalidate(rect);
    }
}
```

When the user releases the mouse, stop drawing:

```
private void MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
}
```

The #1 most important rule in Windows Forms is: **only draw to the screen in the Paint event**. Never never draw in the `MouseMoved` event:

```
private void Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, rect);
}
```

Once you get this working, create a form `List<Rectangle>` and add the current rectangle in the `MouseUp` event and draw all rectangles in the `Paint` event. You might also want to clip your drawing to the panel or window you are drawing in. You can also do some optimizations in `MouseMoved` to only invalidate the changed screen region, not both the old and new rectangles.