# C# - How to Draw a rectangle with pre-determined size after button click + retangle follow move movements + get coords

Tags: c#, coordinates, draw, mousemove

Sorry for my eng. Im quite new to C#, and i need this:

1. After clicking a button, a rectangle form with pre-determined size will appear;
2. This rectangle must move all around the form + move on screen even if the form is minimized;
3. The retangle must follow the mouse movements;
4. When i make a mouse click on the place of screen i want, i need that all coordinates of the area of the rectangle are stored in variables.

This coordinates of rectangle will later be checked by a read-pixel code that i already have, so i really need that the rectangle area of where i clicked really be stored in variables.

EDIT: 
Im really new to c# and what i have done so far is:

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics dc = this.CreateGraphics();
            Pen Bluepen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
            dc.DrawRectangle(Bluepen, 0, 0, 50, 50);
        }
```

And:

```
 private void button5_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
       if (isMouseDown == true)
        {
            rect.Location = e.Location;

            if (rect.Right > pictureBox1.Width)
            {
                rect.X = pictureBox1.Width - rect.Width;
            }
            if (rect.Top < 0)
            {
                rect.Y = 0;
            }
            if (rect.Left < 0 )
            {
                rect.X =  0;
            }
            if (rect.Bottom > pictureBox1.Height)
            {
                rect.Y = pictureBox1.Height - rect.Height;
            }
            Refresh();
        }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: First provide: [mcve]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service; you are expected to [do your own work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [show us what you tried](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). However, you could start by [drawing a rectangle on-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991039/).

Comment: @FCin done!!!!!

Comment: @DourHighArch, done

Comment: You're violating the #1 rule in WinForms; only draw in the Paint event handler. Never draw in the Click (or MouseMoved) handlers. Please get a book or follow a tutorial; this stuff is too complex to learn by trial and error.

Comment: Actually a live-moving Rectangle can also be drawn with CreateGraphics, but not in the button_click but in the mousemove of some canvas control, like a picturebox, not of the button!.. It doesn't need to persist. After MouseUp it should be added to a list of things to draw in the Paint event..

Comment: Indeed it is possible to draw using CreateGraphics, and using many other techniques. But those techniques are not necessary for what @Gabriel wants to do, and he should learn how to draw following the rules before deciding to break them.