# C# Forms - How to draw shape over existing panels

Tags: c#, forms, drawing

[image]

Trying to draw a shape over existing panels for a good while, but by now out of ideas. Could somebody help me out, please? It ends up always behind the panels (and pictureBox /the grey one/). I tried 3 different ways, whithout success. this is my code:

```
namespace DrawingOnFront
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void panel11_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawIt(90, 70);
    }

    private void DrawIt(int x, int y)
    {
        Rectangle Circle = new Rectangle(x,y,40,40);
        SolidBrush Red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.FillEllipse(Red, Circle);

        /*
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        int width = pictureBox1.Width /4;
        int height = pictureBox1.Height /2;
        int diameter = Math.Min(width, height);
        g.FillEllipse(Red, x, y, width, height);
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

        */

    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
        {
            Rectangle Circle = ClientRectangle;
            Circle.Location = new Point(100, 60);                  
            Circle.Size = new Size(40, 40);                       

            using (SolidBrush Green = new SolidBrush(Color.Green))    
            {
                g.FillEllipse(Green, Circle);
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Sorry for this basic lama question, probably for most of you it is very easy, I am still learning it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do not try to draw in your `MouseClick` event; anything you do there will be erased the next time your control is redrawn. Instead, set a form variable to the shape or whatever you need to draw, and invalidate your control. In your `Paint` event handler draw all your content. Consult [How to draw shapes in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071046/22437) for a simple example.

Comment: If you're using PictureBoxes, each PictureBox is a separate control. Controls have a Z-order and the frontmost control always draws over other controls. Please get a book or follow a tutorial; this stuff is too complicated to learn through trial and error.

Comment: _using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)_ you didn't create it, so don't dispose of it nor use using! - _Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();_ Never use this for persisting graphics! - You can't draw over controls, only onto them. Your graphics must either be drawn onto an overlaying control or be drawn onto each panel separately. Ulimately we can't help because we don't know you long-term goal. The usual advice is to draw __all__ things yourself if they are just drawings.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1):

My comments above apply. Here is an example of how to draw **onto each** control and the form **separately**:

We best have a common drawing routine that we can call from the `Paint` event of each participating element, in our case a `Panel`, a `PictureBox` and the `Form`.

The trick is for all nested elements to draw the circle **shifted** by their own location. To do so we pass these things into the  drawing routine:

- a **valid** `Graphics` object. We get it from the `Paint` events.
- and a reference to the control; we use it to offset the drawing on each control (except the form) with `Graphics.TranslateTransform`..:

Result:

As you can see it **looks** as if we painted **one** circle over all elements but actually we drew **three** circles, each onto one element..:

[image]

```
private void canvasForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    draw(sender as Control, e.Graphics);
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    draw(sender as Control, e.Graphics);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    draw(sender as Control, e.Graphics);
}

private void draw(Control ctl, Graphics g)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(200, 100, 75, 75);
    if (ctl != canvasForm)  g.TranslateTransform(-ctl.Left, -ctl.Top);
    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, r);
    g.ResetTransform();
}
```

---

Note that the same result could be created with three calls, one `FillRectangle`, one `DrawImage` and one `FillEllipse` :-)