# Is it possible to have Graphics as a button_click action?

Tags: c#, event-handling, drawing

I'm trying to make a program that draws circles with random colors and sizes when you click a button, but my code doesn't want to use graphics in the EventArgs and if I use System.Windows.PaintEventHandler it doesn't work as a button click.

I've already tried to change it to use the painteventhandler in the designer of the form but it had to convert to eventhandler.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randm = new Random();
        int rand_rood = randm.Next(1, 257);
        int rand_groen = randm.Next(1, 257);
        int rand_blauw = randm.Next(1, 257);
        int rand_x = randm.Next(1, 501);
        int rand_y = randm.Next(1, 501);
        int rand_width = randm.Next(1, 501);
        int rand_height = randm.Next(1, 501);
        Graphics l = e.Graphics;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(rand_rood, rand_groen, rand_blauw));
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, rand_x, rand_y, rand_width, rand_height);
```

(in the form designer)
    this.button1.Click += Button1_Click;

I want my graphics to work in my button event.

Comment: Use the Paint event of the control you are trying to paint on.

Comment: The code belongs in th Paint event. The button should do `targetControlOrForm.Invalidate();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw shapes in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991039/how-to-draw-shapes-in-winforms)