# How can i draw a rectangle in a picture box or in a panel?

Tags: c#

I have a Form with a PictureBox (or Panel) and I want to draw a rectangle in the point (0,0) of this PictureBox. 
How Can i do??

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void DrawIt()
            {
                System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
                System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(50, 50, 150, 150);
                SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
                graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rectangle);
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.DrawIt();
            }
        }`
```

Comment: Is this WinForms? [Draw in the `Paint` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991039/) not the `Click` event.

Comment: _Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();_ This will work but only for __non-persistent__ drawing. The Paint event and `e.Grpahics` is for persistent drawing. Also: Better fill 1st then draw! - Also: Do not leak brushes. (Or Pens..)

Comment: Ok I understand, but i want to know how i can draw a rectangle in the point (0,0) of a pictureBox

Comment: So? Replace the 50,50 by 0,0 ! Note that your code draws onto the Form, not any other control. Do use the Paint event __of the controls__ you want to draw on!! Also: There are the controlCLientSize and ..ClientRectangle properties you should use!

Comment: Can you post an example please?

Comment: Put `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, yourpbox.ClientRectangle);` into the pbox's Paint event!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 150, 150);
            pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawReactangle(pen, rectangle);
            pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(brush, rectangle);
        }
```