# graphics in Form.Shown function are resetting when formComponent loaded

Tags: c#, forms, events

I want to draw a rectangle(using System.Drawing) when form loaded.
So I put my drawing code in Form.Shown EventHandler.
But rectangle was not shown.

I realized that if I use Application.Run(Form) to load form it worked correctly. (rectangle is showing successfully)
But if I use Form.ShowDialog(), after Shown event, components(ex.button) are loaded and graphics are reset.

What do I need to draw my graphics when form loaded not using Application.Run?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test
{
    class test : Form
    {
        private Button button1;
        private Graphics graphics;

        public test()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            this.Shown += this.ShownEventHandler;
        }

        private void ShownEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawRect();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawRect();
        }

        internal void DrawRect()
        {
            this.graphics.FillRectangle((Brush)new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(99, 211);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // test
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "test";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test myTest = new test();
            myTest.ShowDialog();

            //If use this code, rectangle is showing when form loaded
            //Application.Run(myTest);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to draw your rectangle in your form's `Paint` event handler, not the `Click` handler. Consult [How to draw shapes in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991039/),

Comment: You need to be using `Application.Run` because it starts the Windows Message pump, without it you are not properly constructing the windows forms app.